# R x11 on Mac not functioning - or, functioning weirdly

Tags: macos, r, terminal, plot, x11

I have a simple R script in a file Test.r:

```
x11()
plot(1,1)
```

From the terminal, I type "Rscript Test.r" and x11 opens and quickly flashes the plot with a point at (1,1), and then quickly closes the window, however x11 remains open.

How do I keep the plot open? Why does it leave so quickly?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just execute the commands in an R session and use Quartz for graphing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R will close the device when the process R dies (as it does when the script completes). The better way to do this is:

```
pdf("file.pdf")
plot(1,1)
dev.off()
```

then when you run through the Rscript it will save the file there. Otherwise, you'll have to have R stay alive which isn't really how it should be run in a script.

Comment: any idea how to increase the resolution of the pdf? the image in the pdf is kind of crummy looking.

Comment: That the pdf is crummy looking is very surprising; PDF is a vector format so it should have arbitrarily good resolution (e.g. I can zoom in to this picture up to 6400% in Acrobat reader & it still looks fine). How are you viewing it?  Did you paste it into an Office document or something?